# rhomobile application setup

Tags: rhodes

I am tryin to setup the rho mobile for android applications. I am somehow not able to move ahead with it. After downloading instant rhodes and android NDK, how do I move ahead and use it with the android setting?

It asked me to look for rhodes-setup but I couldn't find it anywhere in the system.

```
cd /path/to/android/root 
make
```

is not a valid specified path. I tried it on command prompt. Was it how it was supposed to be?

how am i supposed to run this command?

```
cd /path/to/android/root 
cp development/ide/eclipse/.classpath .
chmod u+w .classpath"
```

Please help me with it

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command prompt and move to your application's directory

Inside your applications directory you can run rhodes-setup